# Merging two dataframes in pandas, multiple same column names. Can't figure out syntax

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have merged my two dataframes in Pandas but I am unable to figure out how to merge two columns with same name (Country and Year).  I am able to merge either Country OR Year, but, not both.

Whenever I merge say, Country, my year columns become year_x and Year_y by default, and vice versa.

Here is my syntax:

merged = pd.merge(left=df, right=df1, left_on='Year', right_on='Year')

Is there a way using this method that I can have both Year and Country?  I tried to find the answer online, used different permutations in the code, such as adding both Country and Year,  but I receive syntax errors every time.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve. If you need to merge two dataframes that have 2 identically named columns (Year and Country), something like this may help:

`merged = pd.merge(left=df, right=df1, on=["Year", "Country"])`